# Sample data service

Tags: service, sample-data, test-data

Some time ago I saw very useful service for creating and populating sample data for your web application. There was beauty web-face to prepare your data via set of grids. And then you can access your sample data through web-service in JSON format (e.g.).

It's very useful for simple web-application development/debugging.

I can't believe, but can't google it.. Just found one similar http://generatedata.com/.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://restipsum.com to generate your own data model